# How to pass a model to Playlist in qml?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have this model which holds the URL of the songs

```
#ifndef PLAYLISTITEM_H
#define PLAYLISTITEM_H
#include<QUrl>
#include <QObject>

class PlaylistItem : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QUrl source READ source CONSTANT)


public:
    explicit PlaylistItem(QUrl& source, QObject *parent = nullptr);
    QUrl source() const;

signals:

public slots:
private:
    QUrl m_source;
};

#endif // PLAYLISTITEM_H
```

I have a **SongManager** class which sets the data to this model and I have set the property in the main.cpp like this

```
SongManager manager;
ctxt->setContextProperty("manager", &manager);
```

When I access the model in QML like this

```
Audio {
    id: music_player;
    autoPlay: false;
    playlist: manager.getSongListByAlbumName("someAlbumName", true)
}
```

i get this error,

```
Unable to assign QJSValue to ::QDeclarativePlaylist*
```

Why did, I get this error, what should I do if I want to override QML elements like PlayListItem with my own model?

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: What type of model is albumListModel? Is it a list? If so, what data does that list have? You must be explicit, is it a QAbstractItemModel?

Comment: Nope, the problem is not with List View, i need to set a model for PlayList  (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qml-qtmultimedia-playlist.html), but it does not accept any models, how do i pass the data?

Comment: I understand that, I do not point out that the ListView has a problem but I want model information since the model must be converted to PlayList, and the model idea can have innumerable interpretations, can it show how it constructs the dataList?

Comment: oops, sorry . The model i want to pass is ObjectItemModel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have this model which holds the URL of the songs

The code that follows is not a model by any QML definition of the term.

`Audio` expects a `Playlist` element, it doesn't say anything about just about any models, even if you had one. Just because a `Playlist` can be used as a model doesn't necessarily mean any model can be used as a playlist. But even if that was possible, surely it would require a model with a `source` role, not an object with a `source` property.

What `manager.getSongListByAlbumName()` returns is at this point a mystery, so only a psychic would be able to answer the question as it is.

Assuming `manager.getSongListByAlbumName()` returns some sort of list that can be iterated from QML, you can use that to populate a `Playlist` by using the respective methods. I presume it will be possible to directly pass a `QList<QUrl>` to `Playlist.addItems(sources)` and just have it work as this particular container type is automatically converted for QML.

Comment: manager.getSongListByAlbumName() returns QList<object*>, so i need to return a QList<url> to convert it to playlist item on qml?

Comment: Yes, you don't really need the `PlaylistItem` class, simply return a `QList<QUrl>` and pass it to an instance of `Playlist` to its `addItems()` function. Also for the future, note the difference between object properties and model roles. If you have a list of objects, even if it can be used as a model in many places in QML, you won't get a model with a `source` role unless you implement a proper model that presents it. Currently, in a view that accepts QObject lists, you will have to actually do `modelData.source` to get the actual value.

Comment: Thanks a lot, QT docs are some what harder for new learners, you made it clear .